Locally superringed space and its canonical subsheaf

I'm physicist and trying to study relation between physics and category.
I got stuck at the notion of canonical subsheaf of nilponent ideal ((13) in the image).
Here $\bar0$ and $\bar1$ denote the even part and odd part of the ring respectively.
I think, for an open set $V$, $\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{M}}(V)$ is a set of $smooth$ $supercommutative$ $ring$ valued functions on $V$ and the odd part is $\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{M},\bar1}(V)$.
Now, is $\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{M},\bar1}^2(V)$ just squared of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{M},\bar1}(V)$ ? Why are these nilponent ideals and canonical?
Thanks for reading.
